# How to use void(*FUNC)(void)

Tags: c, function-pointers, interrupt

I've got a RTOS API which looks like that :

```
ISRInstall(int ISRnum,void(*FUNC)(void)).
```

Yet my desired callback function is `void task(void*)` for I need data input to calculate.

The platform is a SOC with Cortex-A9 duel core HPS with a baremetal BMP supported RTOS.

The API producer suggest me using trampoline as a entrance.

The following is the solution the **NEW BING** gave me

```
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef struct {
    void (*func)(void*); 
    int data; 
} Callback; 

static void trampoline(void* arg) {
    Callback* cb = (Callback*)arg;
    cb->func(&(cb->data));
}

void task(void* arg) 
{
    int* data = (int*)arg;
    // using arg to do some calculations
}

// A given API
void ISRinstall(int ISRnum, void (*FUNC)(void));

int main() {
    int task_data = 42;
    Callback cb;
    cb.func = task;
    cb.data = task_data;
    ISRinstall(1, trampoline);
    trampoline(&cb);
    return 0;
}
```

So is it a correct way to use trampoline as a entrance of void(*FUNC)(void) to transfer the function with argument?

If it is not, then how to use the trampoline function to arrange the functions with arg as CallBack functions?

Thank you

Comment: `ISRinstall` wants a `void (*FUNC)(void)` which means that the ISR does not have a parameter. But you provide a `void task(void* arg)`. This is probably wrong, The àrg` ponter you'll see in `task` will probably point nowhere.

Comment: `API producer` Who exactly?

Comment: A free RTOS producer called uAbassi for baremetal BMP SOC support.@KamilCuk .They are nice, yet their answers are usually brief and lack of key informations to me.

Comment: `void trampoline(void* arg)` cannot get passed as parameter to a function expecting  `void (*FUNC)(void)` - the code generated by the chatbot lie generator is completely  senseless in every aspect and doesn't even compile. By asking Bing you are now more confused and know less about solving the problem than you did before asking it...

Comment: Particularly, what this boils down to is the ISA - does the CPU actually support ordinary functions as ISRs (Cortex M etc) or does it not (most other MCUs on the market). Without even knowing that much, there's no way to write this code.

Answer (score 1):

> it a correct way to use trampoline as a entrance of void(*FUNC)(void) to transfer the function with argument?

The correct way to transfer context is to use global variables. The callback does not take any context. As ISR itself are "global" themselves, handling signals is one of the cases where you have to use global variables.

You could write a wrapper to have a nice interface, something along this, which could be simplified if there's an interface to get fired ISR inside the handler.

```
// ----- C HAL
void ISRinstall(int ISRnum, void (*FUNC)(void));
enum { MAX_NUMBER_OF_ISRS = 5 };

// ------ your library 
void *cookies[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ISRS] = {0};
void (*callbacks[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ISRS])(void *cookie) = {0};
static void trampoline_1(void) { callbacks[1](cookies[1]); }
static void trampoline_2(void) { callbacks[2](cookies[2]); }
static void trampoline_3(void) { callbacks[3](cookies[3]); }
/* etc */
void yourISRinstall(int isr, void (*cb)(void *cookie), void *cookie) {
    callbacks[isr] = cb;
    cookies[isr] = cookie;
    switch (isr) {
    case 1: ISRinstall(isr, trampoline_1); break;
    case 2: ISRinstall(isr, trampoline_2); break;
    case 3: ISRinstall(isr, trampoline_3); break;
    /* etc. */
    }
}

// -------------------------

#include <stdio.h>
int data;
void task(void* arg) {
    int* data = (int*)arg;
    printf("The data is %d\n", *data);
}
int main() {
   yourISRinstall(1, task, &data);
}
```

Real life example: https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/targets/TARGET_STM/gpio_irq_api.c#L220 .

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the API is just with `ISRnum` and `void (*FUNC)(void)` there is no `void*` given for my data struct. Would you mean I should do the tasks like ` void task(void){  get(G_dataA); set(G_dataA);...... }`?

Comment: I do not understand, yes `ISRInstall` takes only `ISRnum` and `void (*FUNC)(void)`, as in the presented code. `I should do the tasks like` I do not understand how "tasks" come into play and how are they related. The presented code represents one function called `task`, which as I understand, serves as an example of "your callback function" with type `void (*)(void *)`. On a real note, using `printf` from an interrupt handler sounds like a very bad idea, interrupt handlers should be atomic.

Comment: This is a convoluted design and I would advise against it - we shouldn't just blindly answer requests here but to call out bad practices. Keep the program simple and the ISRs short. Communication with the ISR should be entirely encapsulated within the driver. The application programmer then communicates with the driver through a setter/getter API, not by passing pointers along. Furthermore, passing along some sort of wrapped pointer opens up all manner of race condition potentials.

Comment: Hi, please correct me if I'm right , @KamilCuk . trampoline in here is simply a  jump function to your task. So basically I can just do ` ISRinstall(TASK1, function1); void function1(void) {  clear_pending(); mytask(&arg); }`?

Comment: `So basically I can just do` Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback function is senseless. An ISR is always a function taking no parameters and having no return value. If the goal here is to register a callback to be called by an ISR, it is still senseless because you should absolutely not call `printf` inside an ISR.

You need to rewrite `task` so that it becomes something that can be an ISR/be called from an ISR, depending on what `ISRinstall` is supposed to do. There is no way around it. Step 1 is to study how interrupts work and what best practices that are used with interrupts.

Comment: Thank you for the willing to help, please ignore the printf for it is the NEW BING's answer. The reason why I set this code is that it is a way to show NEW BING's use of trampoline for pointers like ` void (*)(void)`

Comment: @Alex_Chun Forget about asking confused chat bots - it has literally no clue about anything, particularly not about embedded systems. It's essentially just a lie generator. Read up on some credible study material above embedded systems design and interrupts instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Lundin , I promise I will.Right now could you please give me a rough idea of how to transfer the data to the IRQ callback or should I just using global value to calculate?

Comment: @Alex_Chun Summary of the basics: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/329961/6102